# How to cut file into chuck

Tags: linux, unix, awk, cut, fasta

Consider:

[image]

How can I get information from specimen1 to specimen3 and paste it into another file 'DNA_combined.txt'?

I tried the *cut* command and *[awk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK)* commend, but I found that it is tricky to cutting by paragraph(?) or sequence.

My trial was something like **cut -d '>' -f 1-3 dna1.fasta > DNA_combined.txt**

Comment: Could you please post samples in text form so that it will be easy for us to do testing of code.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67430345/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the line number for each row using `Esc + :`  and type `set nu`
Once you get the line number corresponding to each row:
Note down the line number corresponding to Line containing **>Specimen 1** *(say X)* and **Specimen 3** *(say Y)*
Then, use sed command to get the text between two lines

`sed -n 'X,Yp' dna1.fasta > DNA_combined.txt`

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the first three sequences irrespective of the content after `>`, you can  use this:

```sh
$ cat ip.txt
>one
ACGTA
TCGAAA
>two
TGACA
>three
ACTG
AAAAC
>four
ATGC
>five
GTA

$ awk '/^>/ && ++count==4{exit} 1' ip.txt
>one
ACGTA
TCGAAA
>two
TGACA
>three
ACTG
AAAAC
```

- `/^>/` matches the start of a sequence

  - for such sequences, increment the `count` variable
  - if `count` reaches `4`, the `exit` command will terminate the script
- `1` idiomatic way to print contents of input record

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try the following:

```
awk '
BEGIN {print ">Specimen1-3"}            # print header
/^>Specimen/ {f = match($0, "^>Specimen[1-3]") ? 1 : 0; next}
                                        # set the flag depending on the number
f                                       # print if f == 1
' dna1.fasta > DNA_combined.txt
```